# How to require mount with password of other internal hdd partitions for all mount-style applications (with udev)

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, partitioning, udev, udisks

I am trying to block access to other partitions with different file systems on the same physical hdd (layout: gpt) by preventing any partition mounting without requiring a password.

FSTAB takes care of using mount with password.
If it is not in FSTAB, it will require a password.

For Nautilus and udisks I was trying udev setting ENV{UDISKS_ commands like such:

```
KERNEL=="sda10", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY}="1", ENV{UDISKS_SYSTEM_INTERNAL}="1"
```

I have verified that the ENV are added by using

```
udevadm info --name="/dev/sda10" --query=all
```

But this does not seem to stop (non-gksudo) Nautilus or udisks from mounting the partition when clicked.

I would like it to prompt a password when it tries. As is specified here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/udisks.7.html

> If set, this will override the usual bus type based detection of
>              whether a device is considered "system internal". "0" means
>              "removable" (i. e. eligible for automounting, and normal users can
>              mount), any other value means "system internal" (i. e. no
>              automounting, and only administrators can mount).

Thanks in advance.

P.S.
In contrast using this

KERNEL=="sda10", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"

does stop Nautilus from presenting the partition in the devices section. All though hiding probably does not stop udisks from mounting it anyway (have not tried that).

Comment: Related question about _not_ requiring authentication given new defaults: [Why does my SD card need authentication to access?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188472/why-does-my-sd-card-need-authentication-to-access/235079)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here at Reddit: [How does Ubuntu allow mounting of internal block devices without authenticating?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/6pfx75/how_does_ubuntu_allow_mounting_of_internal_block/)

BTW: I use linuxmint-mate 19.1 (tessa) and 18.3 (Sylvia) both LTS Releases - based on Ubuntu Bionic Package. I didn't test in ubuntu itself.

Just open as root the file`/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` and change the line

```
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;
```

to this one:

```
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;
```

As you can see, just delete this part of the line:

```
org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;
```

So, at each request to mount a partition in Caja, an authentication request window will open to mount it;

You do not even need to reboot or quit your user session.
It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible with `PolicyKit/polkit` rules, rather than editing the `udev` rules directly.

By default on 12.04, mounting is allowed by default.

```
user@precise:~$ pkaction --verbose --action-id org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount
org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount:
  description:       Mount a device
  message:           Authentication is required to mount the device
  vendor:            The udisks Project
  vendor_url:        http://udisks.freedesktop.org/
  icon:              drive-removable-media
  implicit any:      no
  implicit inactive: no
  implicit active:   yes
```

It should be possible to create a local rule which overrides this (see `man pklocalauthority`), and requires authentication to perform this action. Create a file named, eg `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/50-disable-automount.pkla` containing:

```
[Disable automount]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount
ResultAny=auth_admin
ResultInactive=auth_admin
ResultActive=auth_admin
```

You might need to investigate some further details (eg, there are more specific actions like `org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount-system-internal` which presumably applies only to your local hard disks rather than USB sticks, and you can choose either `auth_admin` or `auth_admin_keep` depending on whether you want a recently entered password to be sufficient).

I'm not completely certain of some of the semantics of policykit, and documentation seems to be a bit sparse, so you might need to play a bit, but I think this is the Right way to do it. See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PolicyKitPermissions/12.04) for the default policykit permissions for actions in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have looked at the Policy Kit defaults using your URL, and they seem to be ok. I do not wish to block portable drives, just the internal drives. Also used pkaction to see the local values. I have to verify if Policy Kit is active? Thanks for sending me in the direction of Policy Kit though.